# Getting the minimum x and y origin of an array of NSImageView-subclasses using valueForKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a Cocoa-Application in which I have a NSMutableArray which contains instances of an NSImageView subclass.

What I am trying to do is to get the minimum value for the x value of the ImageViews bounds origin.

I have tried:

```
double minx =[[robots valueForKeyPath:@"@min.bounds.origin.x"] doubleValue];
```

as well as:

```
double minx =[[robots valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self.bounds.origin.x"] doubleValue];
```

However I get the following error:

```
[<NSConcreteValue 0x100597a20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key origin.
```

I have searched the internet and the NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference, but I didn't find a solution for my problem. I know that I could just loop through the NSMutableArray, but using valueForKeyPath would be the better way I guess.

Comment: I understand the error; given `NSRect` is a simple `struct` and not a Objective-C object.

Comment: .... so how about subclassing `NSImageView` and exposing those values as properties?

Comment: The NSImageView is already subclassed anyways. Thanks, that solved the problem. If you post it as answer, i will pick it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `NSRect` (the returned value from `[NSImageView bounds]`) is a simple `struct` and not an Objective-C object.

I would recommend subclassing `NSImageView` and exposing those values as properties so that they are Key Value Coding-Compliant.